# LinkedIn share button only appearing on initial load in AngularJS app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, linkedin-api

I am using AngularJS 1.3 with jQuery 1.11, and I'm trying to add a LinkedIn share button (using the [LinkedIn share plugin generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator)). This button appears in one of my templates, inside a div. Here is my code:

```
<div style="padding: 10px;">
    <!-- Social media icons from sharethis.com -->
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
    <script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right"></script>
</div>
```

This button only appears when I initially visit the page / load the template. If I visit the page again, the button is no longer there (when I inspect the DOM, the script tags are there, however).

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to ascertain what happens. I suggest you create a Plunker. Also, what does "visit the page again" mean - are you reloading the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need reparse dynamically added share buttons. For example with directive:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
            lang: en_US
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="elem in elements">
                <linked-in-share></linked-in-share>
            </div>
            
            <button ng-click="addShare()">Add</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.elements = [0];
                
                $scope.addShare = function () {
                    $scope.elements.push( $scope.elements.length);
                };
            }]).directive('linkedInShare', [function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    template: '<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="top"><\/script>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                        if (IN.parse) {
                            IN.parse();
                        }
                    }
                };
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work in a snippet but it works in separate page.

Comment: Should the same be applied for any social sharing button in Angular? Google and Twitter work just fine as normal, but they be placed in a directive like so in terms of best practice?