# Sign in button does not appear sometimes on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I hve the standard LinkedIn JSAPI script in my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script>
```

I am using Angular.js and have this code in my sign-in page:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="FBlogin()">Connect with Facebook</button> 
<script type="in/Login" data-onAuth="getLinkedInProfile"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // upon getting in.js above, apply to register window scope
    function getLinkedInProfile() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "email-address", "picture-urls::(original)", "industry", "languages", "educations", "three-current-positions", "three-past-positions"])
            .result(function(me) {
              angular.element(document.getElementById('login_window')).scope().linkedInRegistration(me) // calls scope function
            })
            .error(function(error) {
              console.log('>> error on LinkedInLoad', error)
            })
    }
</script>
```

On certain random chances, the button just does not appear at all. I've somewhat noticed that if I removed all the fields() options, then the button will reliably show up, but I'm not if this is the reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what causing this. But angular has a app-life-cycle which parses the HTML, configuring modules, register services, etc. I think if you integrate this function inside an `angular.factory` it should be ok.

Comment: Could you show us where do you call your function? Maybe something does not loads properly.

Comment: The function getLinkedInProfile() is called after data comes back after I login. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no angular expert, but I can tell you that once the user authenticates for the first time, anytime he is logged in into LinkedIn.com, he is automatically logged in into your website and the button disappears.

This only happens with the JavaScript API, and I believe that's what is happening on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed today that the linkedIn login button disappears when state changes. If the button is in state A and state is changed to B and then back to A, the button is no longer displayed. 
I solved it by using a directive to place the button instead of hardcoding it into the view. The solution I used is in an answer to a similar question here at stackoverflow: 
[LinkedIn share button only appearing on initial load in AngularJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169962/linkedin-share-button-only-appearing-on-initial-load-in-angularjs-app)

Hope this helps others coming by :-)